# Why is Hibernate throwing a SQLGrammarException saying table/view does not exist when I've set hbm2ddl.auto to create?

Tags: spring, hibernate, servlets, sqlexception, hbm2ddl

I've been experimenting with hibernate and spring and servlets. Now, I'm stuck. Why am I getting this exception? I thought tables would be created automatically when hbm2ddl.auto is set to create.

***appicationContext.xml***

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db;create=true" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.springpractice.domain" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="cache.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

***UserDetails.java***

```java
package org.springpractice.domain;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    protected int id;
    protected String name;
    protected String email;

    // setters/getters ...
}
```

***Main.java***

```java
@WebServlet("/")
public class Main extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("hello from servlet");

        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setEmail("bob.smith@gmail.com");
        user.setName("Bob Smith");

        ApplicationContext beanFactory =
            WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory)     beanFactory.getBean("sessionFactory");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(user);
        session.close();

    }

}
```

***Exception***

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table/View 'USERDETAILS' does not exist.
org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:146)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
$Proxy10.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property names should be prefixed with hibernate.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.springpractice.domain" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
                org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

BTW there is a simpler way to configure properties as follows

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"=create
        </value>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try annotating your entity with `@Table("USERDETAILS")` and all your fields with `@Column` annotation.

Refer http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html
[Does Hibernate create tables in the database automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507142/does-hibernate-create-tables-in-the-database-automatically)
[Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-question-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)