# Hibernate does not create tables automatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have Maven project with Hibernate and Spring framework.
I want Hibernate to create tables automatically, but all existing tables are just dropped and the required tables are not created.
No exceptions are thrown during session factory initialization, but when I try save a `Player` entity, exception is thrown:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'billboarddb.player' doesn't exist

If I create the tables manually and change the property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `"validate"`, then everything works fine.
Do you have any idea, why Hibernate does not create the tables?

Spring configuration file:

```
<context:component-scan  base-package="org.meluk.billboard.business.controller" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" >
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/config/jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.meluk.billboard.jpa" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

jdbc.properties file:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/BillboardDB
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=1234
hibernate.default_schema=BillboardDB
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
```

Hibernate dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernateToolsVersion}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507142/does-hibernate-create-tables-in-the-database-automatically

Comment: Yes they are similar, but there tables are generated fine.

Comment: Just to give you an idea. If everything is properly configured Check your dialect settings for your database

Comment: I`ve checked it a lot of times.

Comment: How have you defined the enitity, Player? Can you put the code snippet.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed ! It is so relevant and helped me a lot !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I solve the problem. Hibernate could not create tables with MysqlInnoDBDialect.
Now I use MySQL5InnoDBDialect instead.

Comment: I used `MySQLDialect` before and changed it to `MySQL5Dialect` (added the '5'). Did the job, too.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following entry to the hibernateProperties props.

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

Comment: I defined it: "<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>"

Comment: y it is throwing "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException" ? is mappings are all correct ?

Comment: you have put show sql as true right ? take the scripts comming in the logs and run them  directly using your db client. see if it has problems.

Comment: I do not see any sql for drop or create tables. There is only:"INFO: Hibernate: insert into Player (age, email, password) values (?, ?, ?)"