# Hibernate is not auto-creating a table that does not exist in the DB

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a basic Hibernate code, 
I have set the property "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" as update still it is not auto-creating the table in the Database.

These are the required files:

employee.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="contacts.employee" table="contacts">
      <meta attribute="class-description"></meta>
    <id column="contactId" name="contactId" type="string">
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property column="contactName" length="100" name="contactName" not-null="true" type="string"/>
    <property column="password" length="100" name="password" not-null="true" type="string"/>
    <set cascade="all" name="groupOfResponsibilities" table="employee_responsibilty">
      <key column="contactId"/>
      <many-to-many class="contacts.responsibilities" column="responsibilityId"/>

    </set>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

responsibility.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="contacts.responsibilities" table="responsibilities">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class list of responsibilities if an employee
    </meta>
    <id column="responsibilityId" name="responsibilityId" type="long">
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property column="responsibilityName" name="responsibilityName" type="string"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">*****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="contacts/employee.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="contacts/responsibilitiy.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is the Main.java that I am trying to run:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sessionfactory = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Set<responsibilities> groups = new HashSet<responsibilities>();
            responsibilities responsibilityOne=new responsibilities("Java");
            responsibilities responsibilityTwo=new responsibilities("SQL");
            responsibilities responsibilityThree=new responsibilities("Oracle");
            groups.add(responsibilityOne);
            groups.add(responsibilityTwo);
            groups.add(responsibilityThree);
            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            String uuid2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            employee firstEmployee;
            firstEmployee = new employee(uuid, "Mike", groups);
            employee secondEmployee = new employee(uuid2, "Marc", groups);
            session.save(responsibilityOne);
            session.save(responsibilityTwo);
            session.save(responsibilityThree);
            session.save(firstEmployee);
            session.save(secondEmployee);

            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }

    }
}
```

This is the error that I get:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table '****.responsibilities' doesn't exist

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same issue, this worked for me -

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Comment: Also to me. Likely nobody on the Earth can say, why the $§%&"§$ do we have to use sometimes `"hibernate.something"` property and sometimes only `"something"`...

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and i've tried `create` before also but it didn't work. I dont know whether I'll have to open a new question.

Answer (score 24):

The following scenario could be another reason why Hibernate cannot auto-create your table:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private String empID;
  private String name;
}
```

The table `Employee` will not be auto-created by Hibernate since `empID` is a `String` and it has the `@GeneratedValue` annotation. `empID` should be an `int` or `long`. 
I had this problem sometime and I changed my `id` field that had the `@GeneratedValue` annotation to be of type `int` and Hibernate auto-created the table.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, I solved it by changing:

`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect`

to

`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`

I found the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291940/hibernate-does-not-create-tables-automatically).

Comment: Same goes for the spatial versions of the dialects. Hibernate has a lot of mysterious error logs.

Comment: The referred question suggests: `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` instead of `MySQLInnoDBDialect` which worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

1. First, check your MySQL version with `$mysql --version $mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.11`

Then change Dialect accordingly

2. then change the dialect property /For this example I have given `MySQL55Dialect/ org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect`

//////////////////////////////////////////////// --where you can find Dialect:

```
org.hibernate.dialect
try 
import org.hibernate.dialect.ctrl+space
you find option
```

Hope this Help

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but for me the solution was:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
```

instead of

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl">create-drop</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try create or create-drop instead. Seems to serve your purpose.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional

Answer (score 1):

I add to Spring application.properties and work

```
spring.datasource.driver.class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are Using Hibernate 5 or above this will be solved by changing the dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect.
It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

for me, there was space in table name in hibernate annotation. Once removed space, table got created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate can create table, hibernate sequence and tables used for many-to-many mapping on your behalf but  you have to explicitly configure  it by calling setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create") of Configuration object. By Default it just validate the  schema with DB and fail if anything not already exist by giving error "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist".

Answer (score -1):

For the existing working environment, or for any big application area, **it's not recommended to set hibernate.hbm2ddl.autoon create or create-drop** , as it is shown below

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
```

though it works, but it will drop all the existing tables of the database every time you restart the server.

If you are using the **hibernate jar version 5.2.0** then please switch to either lower or any other version.This version jar is having some issue regarding update.

It worked for me and i hope it will work for others too.

Answer (score -1):

after 3 hours In my case i was using wrong groupID and artifact in the packages names.

Answer (score -1):

Adding this in *application.properties* works for me

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Answer (score -2):

Just do correct configuration

1) Create, Every time a new table will create. All Old data will be deleted.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

2) Update, If any modification has done then same will reflect to DB.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: This is not answering the reason for failure. I guess everyone knows what option create or update do. This is a very generic answer, without understanding the question.