# Create database tables from entities

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is in hibernate something like code first approach from Entity Framework?
I am trying to prepare database tables from java classes (MySQL). I have already prepared java classes with JPA annotations, but I am not sure what to do now (I am using IntelliJ). What should I have in my main to create thoose tables? Or should I use some tools?

One of my classes looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String text;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "items")
    private Set<Container> containers = new HashSet<Container>();

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Set<Container> getContainers() { return containers; }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Hibernate create tables in the database automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507142/does-hibernate-create-tables-in-the-database-automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarification: I was using JPA2, so configuration was in **persistence.xml**. What worked for me was setting:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

without **"hibernate."** it was not working.

Also to start it I needed to prepare main function with creating EntityManager, because mapping to db happens when it is created:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit"); //name of persistence unit here
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property with value `create`. If so, when you run the applications first time, the tables will be created.

Answer (score 2):

In hibernate.cfg.xml configuration file you can set a property called `hbm2ddl.auto` that tells hibernate to create a table for you:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

When you run your application for the first time then you can set the property to `create` and later you can change it to `update`.

Follow this link for more details:

[Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "")
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "")
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
```

In my case, I have mentioned the same `OneToMany` relationship two times in a master table. Because I have two relationships. I have used `@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` in two relationships. This is working for me fine.