# unable to create table automatically

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

After performing :Person_Repository.save(Person) ,error message: "Table 'person' doesn't exist"
Isn't the table supposed to be produced automatically?

```
@Entity
public class Person
{
......
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface Person_Repository extends JpaRepository
{ 
}
```

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.21.RELEASE)

2019-08-28 11:25:02.300  INFO 14112 --- [           main] c.s.mirrorworld.mirrorworldApplication   : Starting mirrorworldApplication on LAPTOP-FAS0SHLM with PID 14112 (C:\Users\yueho\eclipse-workspace\mirrorworld\target\classes started by yueho in C:\Users\yueho\eclipse-workspace\mirrorworld)
2019-08-28 11:25:02.309  INFO 14112 --- [           main] c.s.mirrorworld.mirrorworldApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-28 11:25:02.509  INFO 14112 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2f217633: startup date [Wed Aug 28 11:25:02 CST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-08-28 11:25:07.566  INFO 14112 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-08-28 11:25:07.599  INFO 14112 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-08-28 11:25:07.820  INFO 14112 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2019-08-28 11:25:07.823  INFO 14112 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-08-28 11:25:07.825  INFO 14112 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2019-08-28 11:25:07.936  INFO 14112 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-08-28 11:25:08.442  INFO 14112 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-08-28 11:25:09.852  INFO 14112 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-08-28 11:25:14.077  INFO 14112 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2019-08-28 11:25:14.106  INFO 14112 --- [           main] c.s.mirrorworld.mirrorworldApplication   : Started mirrorworldApplication in 12.624 seconds (JVM running for 24.134)
2019-08-28 11:25:32.411  WARN 14112 --- [WT-EventQueue-0] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2019-08-28 11:25:32.412 ERROR 14112 --- [WT-EventQueue-0] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'mirrorworld.person' doesn't exist
2019-08-28 11:25:32.416  INFO 14112 --- [WT-EventQueue-0] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:525)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_Persistence_Service.Save_thing_simply(Thing_Persistence_Service.java:236)
    at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_Persistence_Service.Save_thing(Thing_Persistence_Service.java:63)
    at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_List_Service.Save_thing_list(Thing_List_Service.java:673)
    at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_List_Service.Manage_user_intention(Thing_List_Service.java:73)
    at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p2_base_bean.Thing_Editor_Dispatcher.Manage_user_intention(Thing_Editor_Dispatcher.java:28)
    at com.stepforward.mirrorworld.p4_view.Listener_Thing_List_Editor_View_Button.actionPerformed(Listener_Thing_List_Editor_View_Button.java:38)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2204)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2696)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:980)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:301)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:517)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:515)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:500)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:283)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mirrorworld.person' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2011)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    ... 100 more
```

Comment: Calling `Person_Repository.save(Person)` won't create the table but you can create the table on application startup check the  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507142/does-hibernate-create-tables-in-the-database-automatically for how to do this.

Comment: question addressed, thank you very much.